# How can I convert px to vw in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to convert `px` to `vw` in JavaScript, how can I do it?

I've been looking for it, but I haven't found anything.

So,

> *1px → ? vw*

Thanks.

Comment: [Just get the width of your screen in JS](http://tripleodeon.com/2011/12/first-understand-your-screen) they said. gl;hf

Comment: @errand, I have a use-case for this.  I'm positioning text fields over an image that may be printed fully wide in portrait or landscape and exactly matches what is seen on screen.  Works great until draggable converts field positions from viewport percentages into pixels.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> 1px = (100vw / [document.documentElement.clientWidth] px)

e.g. — If your viewport was `500px` wide (equals by definition to `100vw`) then

> 1px = (100vw / 500px) = 0.2vw

I used `.clientWidth` to [exclude any scrollbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientWidth) from computation

Comment: Note that .clientWidth is a property, not a method.

Comment: right, thank you for your note. :) (need a second morning coffee)

Comment: Why did you exclude the scrollbar? I have observed that 100vw **includes the scrollbar** if one appears. So `window.innerWidth` has been giving me accurate conversions between px and vw. But document.documentElement.clientWidth has not. Tried on Windows Chrome and Firefox, Mac Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 16):

## The formula goes like this

#### px in vw:

100 * px / windowWidth

#### px in vh:

100 * px / windowHeight

#### vh in px:

windowHeight * vh / 100

#### vw in px:

windowWidth * vw / 100


Some code for inspiration: (I'm a JS noob though)

```js
function viewport_convert(px = 0, vw = 0, vh = 0){
    if(px != 0){
        if(vw){
            return (100 * px / window.innerWidth);
        } else {
            return (100 * px / window.innerHeight);
        }
    } else if(vw != 0 && vh != 0){
        var w_h_arr = [];
        w_h_arr["width"] = Math.ceil((window.innerWidth * vw / 100));
        w_h_arr["height"] = Math.ceil((window.innerHeight * vh / 100));
        return w_h_arr;
    } else if(vw != 0){
        return Math.ceil((window.innerWidth * vw / 100));
    } else if(vh != 0){
        return Math.ceil((window.innerHeight * vh / 100));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**As 1vw / 1vh represents 1/100th of the viewport width / height**, you could achieve this using something like :

```
var newWidth = yourElement.outerwidth / document.documentElement.clientWidth *100;
yourElement.style.width = newWidth +'vw';
```

*I thought about use a Math.round() to get clean number, but you'll surely get wrong dimensions if you exclude decimals.*

**Can't you change this values directly in CSS (e.g. with another stylesheet) ? It seems really dirty to convert it via Javascript.**

Also, according to Errand's comment, if you simply convert your px to vw/vh, it won't make your current HTML/CSS magically fit in the screen.