# Percentage or viewport height with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have with the help of Stackoverflow created this Javascript, which checks the height of a div, and if it exceeds the height it does something. This part works great. But I have only been able to get it to work with pixels, right now 300px. My goal is to be able to use either percentage or viewport height, as right now it works differently on different resolutions.

```
if (document.getElementById('vs').clientHeight > 300 ) 
   $('div#vs').addClass('vscroll');
```

Above is the code, how do I use % or vh instead?
I have tried doing > "30vh" but clientHeight doesn't seem to support it!

I cannot find anything which explains how to do this!

Thank you!

Comment: why not use media queries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery height returning px not vh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947652/jquery-height-returning-px-not-vh)

Comment: @August, that thread has no solution from what I can see.

Comment: @jockebq: You can look at this: How can I convert px to vw in JavaScript? - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295072/how-can-i-convert-px-to-vw-in-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: But I don’t understand. My problem is that I cannot write for exemple 40vh instead of 300 (which translates to px)

Comment: No but you could replace with variable which represents a calculation of values from px to vh.

Comment: Do you have any example on how to do this?

Comment: @Daniel A. White, I tried researching this, but appearantly that doesn't work for me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816274/if-div-height-is-larger-than-set-viewport-vh-use-different-css

Comment: Calculating percentage is basic math. Multiply the total height by 0.3 to get thirty percent of the height.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan, yes, but I have no idea how to apply it to my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use js window.innerHeight. Read more:

here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight

And width:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth

Good luck!

Comment: I am not sure how I would apply this?

Comment: Apply that by a.checking the divice's width/height b. translate it to px (you can read how on @August comment) c. putting condition (i prefer the swith case) in order hide/show content. Btw, Why not use css @media?

Comment: A. Meshu, The idea behind Stack Overflow is not to only give links to documentation. With a specific programming question, the person answering the question would give examples of how to fix the code in question with links to supporting information. Your comment should have been moved into your answer with an example of how it is accomplished.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for an example on how to do this, I find no examples of this when searching either.