# jQuery - use css in if statement argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, viewport

I'm using `vw` for previous divs, now I want to set an alert if a div is moved to the very left. Here's the div:

```
<div id='pagination'>some stuff</div>
```

Now its width is set to `84vw`, which was calculated from early functions. I want to alert when its margin-left equals `-84vw`. I tried this in js but no luck:

```
if ($('#pagination').css('margin-left') == '-84vw') {
    alert('you're good to go!');
}
```

Could anyone help me with this argument? The real headache is I can't change `vw` to `px`.

Comment: The syntax error is one case, but your real issue is that `$('#pagination').css('margin-left')` gives you the value in `px`, then you need to convert the value to `vm`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Conversion of `px` and `vw`  refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28295133/5336818)

> 1px = (100 / document.documentElement.clientWidth)vw

**e.g.** — If your viewport was `500px` wide (equals by definition to `100vw`) then

> 1px = (100 / 500) = 0.2vw

Plus you had a syntax error ..Please handle the *quotes* properly

```
alert('you\'re good to go!');
```

Comment: The value from `$('#pagination').css('margin-left')` is coming as `px`. You need to convert.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/4qwzpx52/2/... $('#pagination').css('margin-left') will have always value in PX.. There was an error in the code that you pointed out but your answer is not correct.

Comment: @RinoRaj : i have already edited my answer and have shown him how to convert

Comment: @YoYo You have not included that in your answer.. Please include that too

Comment: @YoYo you'r answer was wrong, so the downvote. That does mean that you can go around downvoting other correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the value units. LHS is `px` and RHS is `vw`.

> 1px = 100 / document.documentElement.clientWidth + 'vm';

```js
var onePx = 100 / document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var valPX = $('#pagination').css('margin-left');
var valVW = Math.round( parseInt( valPX.replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, ''), 10 ) * onePx);
if ( valVW == -84) {
    alert('you\'re good to go!');
}
```

```css
#pagination{
  margin-left:-84vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='pagination'>some stuff</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare pixels to vw, because the `jQuery.css()` always returns the width in [pixels](http://api.jquery.com/css/#entry-longdesc)

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the conditional logic.

The value of the margin depends on the container width, so you can change the element's vw value with container's width value and use this to make your comparison.

You can use the sign of the margin's value for extra control.

```
//Compute the percent width of the element's container
var width = $('#container-of-pagination').width();
var parentWidth = $('#container-of-pagination').offsetParent().width();
var percent = 100*width/parentWidth;
//This will be used for the extra control.
var margin = parseInt( $('#pagination').css('margin-left') );
if ( percent == 84 && margin < 0 ) {
    alert('you\'re good to go!');
}
```