# how can i get element height in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried this and  it just brings an empty space in console of my browser.
How can can i get the height of my element.

```js
var background = document.getElementById('bgimage');
console.log(background.style.height);
```

```css
.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="section s1">
  <div class="background" id="bgimage">
    .......
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get the rendered height of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526347/how-do-you-get-the-rendered-height-of-an-element)

Comment: `element.style.height` refers to ***inline** style only*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `offsetHeight`:

```js
var background = document.getElementById('bgimage');
var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
console.log(background.offsetHeight*100/h);
```

```css
.background {
width: 100%;
height: 500vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="section s1">
<div class="background" id="bgimage">
   .......
</div>
</div>
```

**Note**: `element.offsetHeight` will return height of `element` in pixels (`px`).

Comment: how can i get it back by (vh)

Comment: See updated answer. [Also read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

An element's clientHeight is a measurement that includes the element CSS height and the element vertical padding and, if rendered, subtracting the height of the horizontal scrollbar.

try `background.clientHeight`

Answer (score 0):

Just fix your javascript code

```
var background = document.getElementById('bgimage');
var bgimage = getComputedStyle(background);
console.log(bgimage.getPropertyValue('height'));
```

Comment: can i get this value by (vh);

Comment: This one might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295072/how-can-i-convert-px-to-vw-in-javascript